# Calling PLSQL Procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2013, plsql, asp.net-4.5

I have a project to be started immediately using VS 2013, .NET 4.5.1 and Oracle 12. What I need to do is Using the API that is provided to me, I need to call the procedures that are in PLSQL and get the value of the parameters. From those values I need to generate records for a table. Can someone give me any ideas on how to call those parameters from procedures. I am not sure whether I am posting the question in an understandable manner.

Comment: attach some code what you have tried so far

Comment: @ArunPratap I have no idea where to start and still in the learning process. I need to start developing and thats the reason I approached SO

Comment: You mentioned about API. Is it the API call which calls stored procedure? Or your code needs to call the stored procedure? If it's API, what issue you are facing in calling API? Do you know how to use ADO.NET driver for Oracle to perform database operations in Oracle from .net application_'? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I need to call the stored procedure and get the values of the parameters. How can I do that in C#? Please provide me any samples or articles that I can follow

Answer (score 2):

I would start by suggesting you install the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess NuGet Package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/). It adds the drivers and library to enable connection to Oracle databases. Afterwards, you'll have to configure your connection in the web.config or app.config.

Once you have that installed in your project, connecting to Oracle and executing procedures is very similar to how you would do it with other databases. For example, say you have the following PLSQL package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PACKAGE MYPACKAGE AS 

  PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(
    p_param1    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_param2    IN NUMBER,
    p_output1   OUT VARCHAR2,
    p_output2   OUT NUMBER);

  FUNCTION MYFUNCTION(
    p_param1    IN VARCHAR2,
    p_output1   OUT NUMBER)
  RETURN VARCHAR2;

END MYPACKAGE;
```

The code to execute the procedure would go something like this:

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types;
using System;
using System.Configuration;

//I'm not including the namespace, class or function declaration, but the following should be inside your fuction
// myconnection is the your oracle connection string as defined in your config (web.config or app.config)
using (OracleConnection cnx = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ConnectionString))
{
   cnx.Open();
   // You prepare the statement here
   OracleCommand commProc = new OracleCommand();
   commProc.Connection = cnx;
   commProc.CommandText = @"MYPROCEDURE.MYPROCEDURE";
   commProc.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   // Here you add all the parameters (in and out) for the procedure
   commProc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
   {
       Value = v_param1, //This would be the C# variable or value you're putting in
       Size = 9 //This has to be the expected maximum size for a string value in your PL/SQL code.
    });

    commProc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_param2", OracleDbType.Decimal)
   {
        Value = v_param2, //This would be the C# variable or value you're putting in
    });
   commProc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_output1", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
   {
       Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, //For output params, you don't specify values, but you have to specify direction.
       Size = 500 //This has to be the expected maximum size for the string value in your PL/SQL code.
    });

    commProc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_output2", OracleDbType.Decimal)
   {
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, //For output params, you don't specify values, but you have to specify direction.
    });

   // Here you actually execute the procedure.
   commProc.ExecuteNonQuery();

   // Once the procedure is exectued, you can access the values for the output params using the commProc.Parameters list.
   string v_output1 = commProc.Parameters["p_output1"]?.Value?.ToString();
   decimal v_output2 = (decimal) commProc.Parameters["p_output2"]?.Value;

   // You prepare the statement here
   OracleCommand commFunc = new OracleCommand();
   commFunc.Connection = cnx;
   commFunc.CommandText = @"MYPROCEDURE.MYFUNCTION";
   commFunc.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   // Here you add all the parameters (in and out) for the procedure
   // When calling functions, the first parameter must be the return value expected from the function. Here you can name it as you wish. I usually name them return_value
   commFunc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("return_value", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
   {
       Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, //For return params, you don't specify values, but you have to specify direction.
       Size = 500 //This has to be the expected maximum size for a string value in your PL/SQL code.
    });

   commFunc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_param1", OracleDbType.Varchar2)
   {
       Value = v_param1, //This would be the C# variable or value you're putting in
       Size = 9 //This has to be the expected maximum size for a string value in your PL/SQL code.
    });

    commFunc.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("p_output1", OracleDbType.Decimal)
   {
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, //For output params, you don't specify values, but you have to specify direction.
    });

   // Here you actually execute the procedure.
   commFunc.ExecuteNonQuery();

   // Once the procedure is exectued, you can access the values for the output params using the commFunc.Parameters list.
   string v_return = commProc.Parameters["return_value"]?.Value?.ToString();
   decimal v_output1 = (decimal) commFunc.Parameters["p_output1"]?.Value;
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea of where to start. You can read more about using ODP.NET to connect .NET and Oracle in Oracle's official website: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html

Comment: Thanks for uplaoding the answer. Please excuse my silly wuestion, but where should I add the provided code? I dont see any public classes included in your code

Comment: No problem... the code I gave you is a snippet, everything (except the using imports from the top) would go inside the method of a class where you need to call the Oracle procedure.  I usually create static classes with static methods that can be called from anywhere in my apps.